# Range of functions defined by integrals

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find the range of this:
$$f(x)=\int_{-4}^{x} \sqrt{16-t^2} dt$$

Logically I can see that it would be based on a circle and its maximum value would be where x=4 and its minimum would be at x=0. How would you one find this analytically though?

Comment: Surely the left hand side should be $f(x)$?

Comment: $f$ is increasing, $f(-4)=0,$ and $f(4)$ is one half the area of a circle of radius $4,$ which is $8\pi.$ Your range is $[0,8\pi].$ I'm not sure what "logically" or "analytically" mean here.

Answer (score 1):

The function under integral is nonnegative, so $f(x)$ is (strictly) increasing. Therefore the maximum is at $x = 4$ and minimum at $x = -4$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus what happens if $$ 0 = f'(x) = \sqrt{16 - x^2} \implies \ldots $$

Use the fact that $f$ is nonnegative.

Answer (score 0):

The $f(x)$ represents the area of half circle as shown in graph,so  the range of this $f(x)$ not exceed the half area of circle that has $r=4$,

T[image]he integral